# Ubuntu 18.10 - no sound in Chrome

Tags: sound, google-chrome

I am running Ubuntu 18.10 and chrome Version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit). I have the same problem - no sound in Chrome, but it works fine with everything else, including Firefox. It did not work with 18.04 either.

I have tried both of the solutions offered in 'No sound (audio) in Chrome Ubuntu 18.04LTS' but neither worked.

I have seen numerous other complaints about this issue, but I have yet to find a solution that works for me. I would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: I just now installed chrome 73.0.3683.86 and audio works! The installation procedure was: 1) `wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -` 2) `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'` 3) `sudo apt-get update` and 4) `sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable`. Issue command: `$ google-chrome --version`, you will see the output will be `Google Chrome 73.0.3683.86`. Finally issue command: `google-chrome-stable &` and you will see Chrome browser.

Comment: But this version was not like yours (70.0.3538.77). I hope you won't mind to update your chrome browser to the latest one (73.0.3683.86)!

Comment: You can also access Chrome browser through `Gnome dash` and double-click  `chrome browser shortcut`

Answer (score 0):

> The questioner @Stewart Kluss's Chrome browser version 70.0.3538.77 had audio issues, so the suggestion was to upgrade chrome to the latest version 73.0.3683.86.
>
> I installed chrome 73.0.3683.86 and audio worked!

**The installation Procedure for Google Chrome Browser 64-bit version 73.0.3683.86.**

**Step-1:** First, add (if not added already) the Google Chrome repository on your system using the following command. While using PPA to our system we also receive the latest updates whenever you check for system updates.

```
$ wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
```

Now add the PPA url to the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list` file as per Ubuntu system architecture.

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
```

**Step-2:** Install or Upgrade Google Chrome

After adding Google Chrome repository in our system use following commands to install the latest Google Chrome stable release. If you already have installed an older version, It will upgrade currently installed version with recent stable version.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

**Step-3:** Verify version

`$ google-chrome --version`

[image]
`Figure-1: Google Chrome latest version 73.0.3683.86`

you will see the output will be Google Chrome 73.0.3683.86.

**Step-4:** Launch Google Chrome

After completing step-3 the Google Chrome has been installed successfully on your system. Finally issue command to see Chrome browser:

`$ google-chrome-stable &`

**Note:** You can also access Chrome browser through `Gnome dash` and double-click chrome browser `shortcut`.